# Android App crashes on animated gradient background

Tags: android, kotlin, background, gradient

I have added an animated gradient background to my App, but after a few seconds the app crashes. The EXCEPTION says that a *linear gradient needs an angle attribute*. But there is an angle attribute in every gradient I added to the project. Anybody has a suggestion what I've messed up?

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //background animation
    val constraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
    val animationDrawable = constraintLayout.background as AnimationDrawable
    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000)
    animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(4000)
    animationDrawable.start()

...
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_list"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
...
```

gradient_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_1"
    android:duration="5000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_2"
    android:duration="5000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_3"
    android:duration="5000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_4"
    android:duration="5000"/>
</animation-list>
```

gradient_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:endColor="#044fab"
    android:startColor="#f18127"
    android:type="linear"/>
 </shape>
```

gradient_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#43b4ef"
    android:startColor="#32ff3f"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

gradient_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="70"
    android:endColor="#f674da"
    android:startColor="#38d7bf"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

gradient_4.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="48"
    android:endColor="#e4033e"
    android:startColor="#e6de15"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Here is the log after the crash:

```
2021-06-05 23:23:33.409 5892-5892/com.jakobu.memory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jakobu.memory, PID: 5892
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Linear gradient requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable$GradientState.updateGradientStateOrientation(GradientDrawable.java:2208)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable$GradientState.getOrientation(GradientDrawable.java:2196)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.ensureValidRect(GradientDrawable.java:1273)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:717)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:87)
    at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:21702)
    at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:21636)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21413)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20298)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4372)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4345)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20258)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2755)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
    2021-06-05 23:23:33.421 5892-5892/com.jakobu.memory I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5892 SIG: 9
```

Comment: "Linear gradient requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45" - you have angles of 48 and 70.

Comment: I'm to stupid to read the Log correctly. Thanks a lot guys, couldn't image that there are these strict limitations of the gradient angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in these two files. Gradient angle should be 45 or one of its multiples like 90, 135, 180, 225 ... etc.
So change this to 90
gradient_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#f674da"
    android:startColor="#38d7bf"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

And change this to 45 (the closest to 48)
gradient_4.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#e4033e"
    android:startColor="#e6de15"
    android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: why is that a problem? i tested this and on some phones it works without multiple of 45 and on some phones this exception is thrown, why??

Comment: You can read here about it https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#:~:text=Integer.%20The%20angle%20for%20the%20gradient%2C%20in%20degrees.%200%20is%20left%20to%20right%2C%2090%20is%20bottom%20to%20top.%20It%20must%20be%20a%20multiple%20of%2045.%20Default%20is%200.

They state on the official docs that "It must be a multiple of 45." So, my guess is that some devices modify the OS, allowing angles other than 45.
I don't know why would Google set such limitations!

Comment: yes I read that same thing, it doesn't provide extensive explanation. i think you're right saying some devices have modified OS allowing angles other than 45.

Comment: @soggypants i found that it is crashing on android 10 (emulator or device), but working well on some other android versions i've tested

Answer (score 0):

create the xml (End and Start)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:startColor="@color/blue_dark"
    android:centerColor="@color/blue"
    android:endColor="@color/blue_cian"
    android:angle="180"/>
```

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:startColor="@color/blue_cian"
    android:centerColor="@color/blue"
    android:endColor="@color/blue_dark"
    android:angle="180"/>
```

create the xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_start" android:duration="2000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_and" android:duration="2000" />
```

put the following code in your activity:

```
val gradient = imageView.background as AnimationDrawable
    gradient.setEnterFadeDuration(10)
    gradient.setExitFadeDuration(200)
    gradient.start()
```

add to your element

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_animation"
```